# How to get 2 ints from cin in C++?

Tags: c++, cin

I'am trying to get three pairs of int from user. But if i enter letters my code ran into infinitive cycle. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

istream& operator>> (istream& is, Point& pt)
{
    int x, y;
    is >> x >> y;
    if (!is) 
        return is;
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Point> points;
    Point pt;
    while (true)
    {
        if (cin >> pt)
        {
            points.push_back(pt);
            if (points.size() == 3)
                break;
            continue;
        }
        cout << " error, try again" << endl; 
        cin.clear();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << "(" << points[i].x << ", " << points[i].y << ")" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while (true) ...` loop never stops. The `break` never executes because `cin >> pt` keeps failing. You can't fix this with simple istream operations, since cin >> pt will never succeed once you've supplied bad input. Either expect correct input, and fail outright if it isn't:

```
while (points.size() < 3 && (cin >> pt))
{
    points.push_back(pt);
}
if (points.size() < 3) throw "up";
```

or read the input as a string and parse it as a separate operation.

While we're at it, simplify your extractor:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& pt)
{
    Point p;
    if (is >> p.x >> p.y) pt = p;
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `cin >> pt` fails, it leaves the end-of-line character in the stream. This causes the next extraction to fail immediately, creating the infinite loop.

Add `cin.ignore()` to the end of the loop to remove the end of the failed line; then the next extraction will wait for more input.